# NEST ELASTICSEARCH Mappings does not works

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to NEST ElasticSearch and have a Class named document as below

```
[ElasticType(Name = "EnterpriseSearch.Document")]
public class Document
{

    public Document()
    {
    }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Integer, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, IndexAnalyzer = "snowballstopAnalyzers", TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating Index and trying to Map this using below code.

```
public void CreateDocumentIndex(string indexName = null)
{
    if (!this.client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
    {
        IndexSettings settings = GetIndexSettings();

        this.client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
            .InitializeUsing(settings)
            .AddMapping<Document>
            (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.String(a => a.Name(o => o.Documents)))));

        this.client.Map<Document>(p => p.MapFromAttributes());
    }
}
```

Basically I want to apply IndexAnalyzer to attribute Documents in class Document. But it is not working. While debugging I noticed that Mappings count is zero if I check property using below code

```
var r = this.client.GetIndexSettings(i => i.Index(indexName));
```

Any Help?

Manish

Comment: May you share `GetIndexSettings` method and how do you defined snowballstopAnalyzers analyzer?

Comment: what version of nest are u using ?

Answer (score 0):

check the mapping of the index like this :

```
http://10.0.0.11:9200/{index_name}/{mappingType}/_mapping?pretty
```

Most of the times the mapping is "killed" by the bad implementation of the analyzers. If you could put the full example that you have it will be more easy to help you.